# Windows Phone 7 - how to determine which row should resize when keyboard is visible?

Tags: windows-phone-7

My problem is that I've got grid with rows:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="139"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="72" />
        <RowDefinition Height="482*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="75" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and I want to have top of the third row visible when keyboard shows up, but unfortunatelly everything goes up (above visible area).

How to fix it? I've thought about determining somehow which row should resize, but I don't know if it is possible.